Can I merge LAN and Wi-Fi traffic from the same router?
I'm not really into Wi-Fi pentesting and my question might be a silly one, so please answer with simple words.
Can I merge Wi-Fi and LAN traffic with my router so that I can capture packets from my phone/laptop using Wireshark on my PC that is connected via ethernet cable? My router model is TPLink Archer A64

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

With managed Ethernet switches have configured a port mirror to send all traffic for one or more ports to a different port for monitoring by Wireshark.
Looking at the Archer C64 User Guide I can't see any mention of support for a port mirror in the management options. I.e. don't think that the Archer A64 router with TPLink firmware supports capturing all Wifi traffic and mirroring to an Ethernet port for packet capture on a connected PC.
On searching have found some suggestions that OpenWRT may allow port mirroring to be enabled on routers, but haven't yet found anything definitive for a TPLink Archer A64.
